# Eu fiz 2 loops q funcionem mas preciso que eles estejam dentro de outro e não fazer isso

Tags: python, loop

```
from time import sleep
import pyautogui

n: int = 1
acumulador = 1
c1: int = 1
c2 = 1
pyautogui.keyDown('alt')
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.keyUp('alt')
pyautogui.move(1300, 100)
pyautogui.drag(0, 90, 2)
while n:=1:
   while acumulador <=2:
    pyautogui.click(500, 630)  # 1
    sleep(3)
    pyautogui.click(700, 300)  # 2
    sleep(0.1)
    pyautogui.click(700, 400)  # 3
    pyautogui.click(800, 700)  # 4
    sleep(3)
    acumulador = acumulador + n
       print(acumulador)

else:
    pyautogui.click(500, 700)  # 5
    sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click(400, 630)  # 6
    sleep(3)
    acumulador - acumulador
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom o seu primeiro `while` esta rodando infinitamente. poderia ser substituido por `while True:`

então logo que você sai do segundo while quando a a condição retorna você nunca vai entrar no seu bloco `else`

rode esse exemplo e olha o prompt enquanto executa:

```
from time import sleep
import pyautogui

n: int = 1
acumulador = 1
c1: int = 1
c2 = 1
pyautogui.keyDown('alt')
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.keyUp('alt')
pyautogui.move(1300, 100)
pyautogui.drag(0, 90, 2)
while n:=1:
    while acumulador <=2:
        pyautogui.click(500, 630)  # 1
        sleep(3)
        pyautogui.click(700, 300)  # 2
        sleep(0.1)
        pyautogui.click(700, 400)  # 3
        pyautogui.click(800, 700)  # 4
        sleep(3)
        acumulador = acumulador + n
        print(acumulador)

    print("estou travado aqui e nunca vou entrar no else")

else:
    pyautogui.click(500, 700)  # 5
    sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click(400, 630)  # 6
    sleep(3)
    acumulador - acumulador
```

agora se você substituir o `print` por `break` acredito que vá resolver

rode esse agora e vê se é o que você precisa:

```
from time import sleep
import pyautogui

n: int = 1
acumulador = 1
c1: int = 1
c2 = 1
pyautogui.keyDown('alt')
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.keyUp('alt')
pyautogui.move(1300, 100)
pyautogui.drag(0, 90, 2)

while True:
    while acumulador <=2:
        pyautogui.click(500, 630)  # 1
        sleep(3)
        pyautogui.click(700, 300)  # 2
        sleep(0.1)
        pyautogui.click(700, 400)  # 3
        pyautogui.click(800, 700)  # 4
        sleep(3)
        acumulador = acumulador + n
        print(acumulador)
    
    break
    
pyautogui.click(500, 700)  # 5
sleep(1)
pyautogui.click(400, 630)  # 6
sleep(3)
acumulador - acumulador
```